# htaccess: how to forward a request to a forbidden folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**desired**:

1. user calls `domain.tld/download/file_01.zip`
2. htaccess calls `private/download.php`
3. `file_01.zip` starts to download

**Note**: `file_01.zip` must be protected from direct access.

Simplified **folder structure**:

```
root/
    public/
        .htaccess
        index.php
    private/            <<< this area is blocked from direct access >>>        
        files/
            file_01.zip            
            file_02.zip
        .htaccess
        download.php
```

**public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)?$ ./../private/download.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

**private/.htaccess** (Edit)

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

**download.php**

```
$file = 'files/'.$_GET['file'];

// check: user allowed to download?
// check: more stuff (security, etc.) ...

forceDownload($file);
```

The RewriteRule works, but I'm getting the error `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access [...] on this server`, probably because *the user* calls the request, not *the server*.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you blocking your access to the `private/` directory?

Comment: @Darren Please take a look now, I added the content of `private/.htaccess`. I can't change the file due to update security.

Comment: If the file/directory is not accessible to Apache then you cannot access it, _full stop_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more approach. Rename particular directory (add a single dot before it's current name, `.private` for example) and place this inside .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

After adding this rule, each and every file and directory that begins with one `.` will be forbidden/protected, just like .htaccess it self is. :)

This will prevent access to anyone but PHP to open, view, modify file/dir contents.

Here is sample of (very common I believe) basic .htaccess *(sitting in DOCUMENT_ROOT directory) mod_rewrite rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Once that this is being done, You don't serve direct links to .zip or whichever file ext. You have in mind, but do that in some other fashion with favorite PHP 'tricks' of Yours. :)

If You feel that this will give You a lot of code refactoring, just because one directory, You can add those dots to zip files, and move them elsewhere, direct access to dotted files, still won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As [RiggsFolly stated *in their comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582909/htaccess-how-to-forward-a-request-to-a-forbidden-folder/34582996#comment56911224_34582909).

You need to modify that `private/` .htaccess file to something like:

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 #or your server address/etc
</IfModule>
```

---

Here is another solution, giving that your Apache version is **`>=2.4`**. (via using [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require))

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```